# Joining intersecting paths in illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Short term problem: I have three paths on an artboard. The end of one path has a point at the same position as the beginning of another. The other path is separate. They are all grouped. I have some code that loops through the pathsin the group, and if one path ends where another begins it tried to join them together. The group must be highlighted. To start with my artboard look like this (The top line is two paths):
[image]

An after the script is run it looks like this:

[image]

With a lot of points added to the end of the line underneath. Could someone lend me a hand with this, Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
var doc = activeDocument;//Gets the active document
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var intersections = true
var group = doc.selection[0]
var paths = []
var intersecttions = 0

// Builds an array of all the paths in the grouped object
if (group !== undefined && group.pageItems.length >= 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < group.pageItems.length; i++) {
        var item = group.pageItems[i];
        if (item instanceof PathItem) {
            item.id = 'Path No' + i;
            paths.push(item)
        }
    }
}

//Sets the first path that will be added to
$.write('paths length ', paths.length,'\n')
var chain = paths[0]
var chainPoints = chain.pathPoints
var chainLength = chainPoints.length - 1
var c1 = chainPoints[0]
var c2 = chainPoints[chainLength]
$.write('c ', c1.anchor,':::', c2.anchor,'\n')

//loops through the paths in the group to see if any overlap the first past
for (var i = 1; i < paths.length-1; i++) {
var link = paths[i]
$.write(link, '\n')
var linkPoints = link.pathPoints
var linkLength = linkPoints.length - 1
$.write('l ', l1.anchor, ':::', l2.anchor, '\n')

if (toString(c1.anchor) === toString(l2.anchor)) {
    $.write('inttersection', '\n')
    $.write('link', link.id, '\n')
    for (var j = 0; j < linkLength; ++j) {
        chain.pathPoints.add(linkPoints[j])
        $.write (linkPoints[j], '\n')
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that it's not detecting the instance of overlap correctly. The line:

```
if (toString(c1.anchor) === toString(l2.anchor)) {
```

is not comparing one string to another but comparing a true response with another true response. It should be:

```
if (String(c1.anchor) === String(l2.anchor)) {
```

you also have to pass across the attributes of each point you are adding to the line and remove the old line, so within the j loop you'll need to add the following

```
for (var j = 0; j < linkLength; ++j) {
        var pp1 = chainPoints.add()
        var p2i = linkPoints[j];
        pp1.anchor = p2i.anchor;
        pp1.rightDirection = p2i.rightDirection;
        pp1.leftDirection = p2i.leftDirection;
        pp1.pointType = p2i.pointType;
        pp1.handle = p2i.handle;
    }
link.remove();
```

This seems to work except that it doesn't add the last point of the second line. I'm guessing that the loop length may not be set correctly If I work it out I'll update the post. I found this in Hiroyuki Sato code for his JoinReasonable scripts http://shspage.com/aijs/en/

Comment: Changing the loop constructor to the following should fix this bug:
var j = 0, jend = linkPoints.length; j < jend; ++j